# How to create typescript interface for fixed numeric properties

Tags: angular, typescript

e.g. I need a interface for this type of object

```
{
    123: "test value"
    124: "test value"
    125: "test value"
    126: "test value"
}
```

I know IField `{ [fieldId: number]: string; }`, but this will take any number as property. Can we restrict this to just my four numbers something like below:

```
export interface IField {
123: string;
124: string;
125: string;
126: string;
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with `interface IField {
  123: string;
  ...
}` ? Your code works..

Comment: It allows any number and dont throw error for oother numeric property

Comment: Then you have an issue with you TypeScript language service or something else, because I definitely get errors if I try with a random number as key, just like  `Type '{ 1: string; }' is not assignable to type 'IField'.`

Comment: @SushilAdokar Have you enabled strict mode in your tsconfig?

Comment: No strict mode is not enable will check wiht strict mode

Comment: @DanielB If I do abc: IField; and then 
this.abc['777'] = 'some value';  ie. invalid numeric key, this is allowed. But I think looks like it is allowed for every interface. Here I have assigned value using array key  like notation

Comment: Please consider modifying the code in this question so as to constitute a [mcve] which, when dropped into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground](https://tsplay.dev/m3AqLw), clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing. Currently [your proposed interface works exactly as you want it to](https://tsplay.dev/m3AqLw), so you should check your local environment for the difference.  As @BenjaminLüscher suggests, it could be as simple as you not turning on the proper type checking compiler flags like `--strict`, and therefore your question has little to do with numeric properties.

Comment: Thanks! I will check my local environment